# how do i combine 2 reducers if one returns an object and the other returns one property of the object?

Tags: redux, react-redux

My problem is I have 2 reducers, 1 returns an "user" object, and the other returns a number, which is actually a property (user.entries) of the "user" object.

When I tried to combine these 2 reducers, I want my 2nd reducer to update the property of User object directly, but I don't know which way I could do it.

Code what I said is like:

```
const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_LOADED':
      return action.payload; // an "user" object
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const entriesReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ENTRIES':
      return action.payload; // a number
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  user.entries: entriesReducer // i know this is not correct...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Structure is wrong , you should use combineReducers only for siblings. Here entries is a child property of User. Better write both together like this.

```
    const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'USER_LOADED':
         return action.payload; // an "user" object
       case 'ADD_ENTRIES':
           return {...state, entries:action.payload};
       default:
         return state;
     }

    };

   export default combineReducers({
     user: userReducer, 
   });
```